# changing variables of elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, affine-geometry, singularity, affine-schemes, projective-varieties

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over field $K$ defined by affine curve

$E:y^2 +a_1 xy+ a_3y  =x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_4x + a_6$（all coefficients are in $K$）

By changing variables, $z＝-x/y$,$w＝-1/y$

We get new affine curve

$E':w＝z^3＋a_1 zw+ a_2z^2w＋a_3w^2 + a_4zw^2 + a_6w^3$

My question is, why $E'$（strictly speaking, projective closure of $E'$）is still elliptic curve?

How can I formally prove that?

My approach: If $E'$ is proved to be smooth, then genus formula deduces $E'$ has genus 1,
and it has also base point, so is elliptic curve.

So,My question is that : How can I show $E'$ is smooth curve?（Is there no choice but to use Jacobi criteria?）

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Genus is a birational invariant

Comment: E' is just a standard affine open subset ($Y \neq 0$) of the projective closure of E, hence smooth.

Comment: Thank you comments. Affine open subset of smooth projective variety is always smooth? Could you tell me why or reference?

Comment: Projective closure of $E$ and projective closure of $E'$ is not the same projective curve.

Comment: A variety is smooth if it is smooth at all its points (over an algebraic closure of the base field). So yes, an open subvariety of a smooth variety is again smooth.

Comment: Well no, I noticed too late that there is a minus sign in the definition of $z$. So on replacing $z$ by $-z$, you do obtain a curve $E''$ isomorphic to $E'$ which does have the "same" projective closure as $E$ (meaning that the equations are the same up to a relabeling of coordinates).